# how to display the role of each user in my index and view in YII2?

Tags: yii2

I have all the RBAC tables in my database, and an user table.
I manage to assign a role when creating and updating an user, it updates the auth_assignment table with the `user_id`, for each `item_name` (the role).

My question is - I want to have another column in my `user/index` screen which will show me what is the role of each user, and also in the `user/view`.

Until now, everything I tried isn't working, I tried joining the user and `auth_assignment` tables but it's not helping - it says there are no relation with `auth_assignment`.

The code:

**`models/User.php`**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use \yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Project;



/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $auth_key
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public $role;

    public static function getRoles()
    {
            return ['admin'=>'admin','releaseManager'=>'releaseManager','pm'=>'pm','psw'=>'psw','qa'=>'qa'];
    }   

    public function afterSave($insert,$changedAttributes)
    {
            $return = parent::afterSave($insert,$changedAttributes);

            $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
                $roleName = $this->role;
                $role = $auth->getRole($roleName);
                if (\Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($this->id) == null)
                {
                    $auth->assign($role, $this->id);
                }
                else
                {
                    $db = \Yii::$app->db;
                    $db->createCommand()->delete('auth_assignment',['user_id' => $this->id])->execute();
                    $auth->assign($role, $this->id);
                }

            return $return;
    }   

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username', 'password','projectId','role'], 'required'],
            [['username'], 'unique']            
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'projectId' => 'Project Id',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
        /*  'role' => 'Role',*/
        ];
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('You can only login
                            by username/password pair for now.');
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->isCorrectHash($password, $this->password); 
    }
    private function isCorrectHash($plaintext, $hash)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($plaintext, $hash);
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
         return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        $return = parent::beforeSave($insert);

        if ($this->isAttributeChanged('password'))
            $this->password = Yii::$app->security->
                    generatePasswordHash($this->password);

        if ($this->isNewRecord)
            $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(32);

        return $return;
    }

    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::className(), ['id' => 'projectId']);
    }

    /*public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::findByUsername($username)->getId() );
    }*/



    public static function getUsers()
    {
        if (\Yii::$app->user->can('assignUsersToPost'))
        {
            $users = ArrayHelper::
                map(self::find()->all(), 'id', 'username');
                //$users[null] = "All Users";
        } else {
            $users = ArrayHelper::
                map(self::find()->where(['id'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->all(), 'id', 'username');         
        }
        return $users;                      
    }
    public static function getCurrentUser()
    {
        $user = ArrayHelper::
                map(self::find()->where(['id'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->all(), 'id', 'username');         

        return $user;                       
    }
/*  public static function isSenderOrRciever($message)
    {
        $return = false;
        if (
            $message->fromUserId == Yii::$app->user->id
            || $message->toUserId == Yii::$app->user->id
        ) 
        $return = true; 
        return $return;
        }   */
}
```

**`UserController. php`** (creating and updating an user):

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();
        $roles = User::getRoles();

        if (isset($_POST['User']['role']))
            $model->role = $_POST['User']['role'];


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'roles' => $roles,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing User model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $roles = User::getRoles();
        $model->password = null;

        $db = \Yii::$app->db;
        $command = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM auth_assignment WHERE user_id=:id');
        $command->bindValue(':id',$model->id);
        $assignment = $command->queryOne();
        $model->role = $assignment['item_name'];

        if (isset($_POST['User']['role']))
            $model->role = $_POST['User']['role'];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'roles' => $roles,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

`'views'` files have no change except the `_form`, because everything I try gives me an error.
From what I understand I just have to add a code to the `index.php` and `view.php` file in order to make it work, but it's been 1 week and I still didn't find the solution.

Thanks in advance,
Jenny

Comment: As a side note, it's generally inconvenient to have methods that return actual models or data like your `getUsers()`. It's a much better practice to have methods that return queries that you can then modify before running `->all()`. Imagine your `User` model returning a list of all posts as an array of models. If you then wanted to get only models that match a specific condition, you'd get _all_ models first and then discard some of them in PHP. It's much better for a method to return a query, so that you can further modify it with `->andWhere()` and get only the data you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GridView you can always create a column with a function that returns whatever data you need. So, in your index view in column definitions add this:

```php
[
    'header' => 'Roles',
    'value' => function($data) {
        $roles = \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($data->id);
        if ($roles) {
            return implode(', ', array_keys($roles));
        } else {
            return 'no roles';
        }
    }
],
```

As you can read in the docs, `getRolesByUser` returns you an array of roles indexed by role name. That's why we're using keys to display roles.

If you plan to filter or sort on that column, you'd have to implement a proper relationship (`getRole()` in your case). Otherwise you can just use `authManager` to get the roles.

This is not going to work with DetailView, though, because you can't pass a function to it. In that case you can just implement this function in your model:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    //...
    getRoleAsText()
    {
        $roles = \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($this->id);
        if ($roles) {
            return implode(', ', array_keys($roles));
        } else {
            return 'no roles';
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

After that you can reference it in both GridView and DetailsView: `['label' => 'Role', 'value' => 'roleAsText']`.

Comment: I'm now trying to show the roles also in view, but I'm getting "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" error. I added this code to the DetailView: 
[
    'label' => 'Role',
    'value' => \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($data->id),
    
   ],

Comment: I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function which returns the array of user roles with index roleName

```
$roleArr = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($data->userid);
```